# Error occurring when trying to install nodemon

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

When I try to install Nodemon I get this error message

```
pm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon
/usr/local/bin/nodemon -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/nodemon.js
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package generator-karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angular@0.5.1 wants generator-karma@~0.6.0

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "nodemon"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/stephenadams
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.18
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/stephenadams/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Looks like the problem is with the package generator-karma, not sure if this is the problem or not.

Can anyone show me what i need to do to get this installing correctly.

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 2):

These lines show the issue:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package generator-karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angular@0.5.1 wants generator-karma@~0.6.0
```

You have a package called generator-karma that is below version 0.6.0 that the package generator-angular needs. I don't believe this has anything to do with nodemon (it should have actually installed), but it's mismatch versions between generator-angular and generator-karma.

Unless you need some specific, older version of generator-karma, simply update it by running:

```
sudo npm update -g generator-karma
```

Comment: Does not help - `Karma version: 0.10.8` but still the same error

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev, that is a different package from `generator-karma`. Did your error show `Peer packagename@version wants Karma@~0.10.8`?

Comment: Sorry I have confused packages. Seems like the problem was caused by other package wanting lower version of `generator-karma`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions :

1. Try using `npm cache clear` then `npm i`
   But this did not work for me.

---

2. The following trick worked for me:

- I added an entry for nodemon in my package.json and specified a version
  Hit `npm install` in the terminal. Finally, I could see nodemailer folder in the node_modules.
- Added an entry in my package.json as follows:
  `"scripts": { "serve": "nodemon server.js" //server.js being my launch file }`
- Hit `npm run serve`
  And, nodemon started working like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command, it worked for me:

```bash
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```